# All functions in Q.all block are not being promised

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, q

I have the following code below in a then block

The issue I'm facing is at the end when i do the res.json(optionData1) its not returning the fully completed js data object i.e. the output after the processData function is missing

Am i using Q.all in the correct way?

```
var processUserInfo = function(categoryToProcess, inputToProcess, optionComingIn) {

  var d = Q.defer();    

  if (optionData1['option'] == optionComingIn) {
    if (optionData1[categoryToProcess].hasOwnProperty(inputToProcess)) {
      optionData1[categoryToProcess][inputToProcess]++;
    } else {
      optionData1[categoryToProcess][inputToProcess] = 1;
    }
    d.resolve(optionData1);
  }

}

var processData = function(item, optionComingIn) {
  var d = Q.defer();
  return User.find(
    {_id: item},
    {gender: 1, country:1},
    function(req, foundUser) {
      processUserInfo('gender', foundUser[0]['gender'], optionComingIn)
      .then(function(resolve,reject) {
          d.resolve();
      });
    });
    return d.promise;
  }


  Q.all(foundQ[0]['people'].map(function(item) { // Or Q.allSettled
    processCounts(item['optionSelected']);
    processData(item['userID'], item['optionSelected']);
  }))
  .then(function(){
    res.json(optionData1);   //Doesnt give me the full result
  });
```

Thanks

UPDATE: Using the return method as in the answer below got everything working.

Comment: you are not using `.map` correctly - read how to use [.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: `processData` must return promise, not User.find

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly but would the use of `d.resolve();` do that?
I have also tried using a then once the user is found but to no luck i.e. `.then(function(req, foundUser) {
          processUserInfo('gender', foundUser[0]['gender'], optionComingIn);
        });`

Comment: @JaromandaX could you please tell me how i'm using wrong, its returnin the item and i'm passing the value in functions - isnt that what map does?

Comment: the function called by `map` is not returning anything - there is no `return` statement in the code you posted

Comment: @JaromandaX those 2 functions actually update an JS object created `objectData1` earlier in the code. I just want them 2 functions to complelty run then give me teh result.

Comment: oh I see ... so you're using `.map` where you could just as easily use `.forEach` - and in that case, you are not using promises at all, like @MedetTleukabiluly - processData isn't returning a promise anyway, and Q.all isn't getting any promises to `wait` on

Comment: So the map isn't required, but in this case i cant see it doing harm. Is the issue then i'm not using promises at all i.e. nothing is actually returing them?

Comment: @JaromandaX so i've updated my code - see above. In `processData` I can see the console.log(resolve) is definetely returing the completed data. though i'm still having an issue with `res.json(optionData1)` not being complete. ANy tips on what i'm missing now?

Comment: you're missing how to use Promises - the code you've changed is nowhere near the code you needed to change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is code which may work - too much "unknown" in your code snippet to be sure

- modified `processData` to return a promise that resolves when `user.Find` is done
- added a return in the `.map`, so the promise returned by `processData` is waited on in `Q.all`

So ... here's the fixed code (processuserInfo unchanged so omitted form the answer)

```
var processData = function (item, optionComingIn) {
    // return a promise to wait for
    return Q.promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        User.find({
            _id: item
            }, {
                gender: 1,
                country: 1
            },
            function (req, foundUser) {
                processUserInfo('gender', foundUser[0]['gender'], optionComingIn);
                resolve();
            }
        );
    });
}


Q.all(foundQ[0]['people'].map(function (item) { // Or Q.allSettled
    processCounts(item['optionSelected']);
    return processData(item['userID'], item['optionSelected']);
    // return added
}))
.then(function () {
    res.json(optionData1); //Doesnt give me the full result
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this. I found as soon as I placed that `return` in everything worked using my original code.
I read through your code and that made sense to me however for some reason its not working. I noticed you have `d.resolve();` by that i presume its referring to `var d = Q.defer();`

Comment: Awesome! Am happy with that. 
Will will use your solution in my code. However can i confirm is my version also acceptable (although not as clear as yours)? It gave me the result i wanted - is that just luck or in essence is it ok?

Comment: I can't see how your version would work ... Q.all still wont get any promises to wait on ... if you have the return in the .map `return processData ..` then it's functionally the same as this answer ...